# Check two columns to see if a pair of elements are both greater than separate minimums?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I use Google Sheets to track my student's reading speed and comprehension scores. They have a goal to increase their reading speed N% over the semester, but that speed will only be accepted if they also get a minimum score on their comprehension questions. The speed is recorded in one column, and the corresponding comprehension score in the column next to it.

I want to write a Google Sheets function that will check the two columns of numbers and tell me if the reading speed is above their goal AND the comprehension score is above the minimum.

For example, let's say the student's reading goal is 202 wpm with a minimum acceptable comprehension score of 5. Given the following reading speeds and scores, the first three rows would not meet the goal since either the speed or comprehension score fail to meet the minimums. The fourth row would be the first to produce a positive result.

```
Speed   Score
 - 171 | 6
 - 205 | 4
 - 200 | 6
 - 206 | 7
 - 210 | 6
```

I've banged my head against this one, but I keep running into trouble. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a link to a sample sheet with my current incomplete attempt at a solution: [Sample Reading Rate Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1smReElCQmS3Q8W45EgcCM96JKjQO1BUtbaGbw3mTrjE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @player0 Thanks for the suggestion (sorry...it's my first time?). I added it above. I'll check out your solution and see if that works. You've laid yours out a little differently than mine, so I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @DCTID Thanks! Sorry for not including an example--my confusion was at the conceptual level. I really didn't even know where to start. It was really easy to come up with a solution that only checked to see if there were any speeds above the goal, and I used that last semester, but I ran into the problem of a student achieving the needed reading speed but not the minimum comprehension score. When I tried to put anything together, I got errors because I have no idea how to combine the two checks. I added a link to my current solution above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, F:G, 2, 1), 9^9)<=C2:C, "PASS", "FAIL")))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((C7:C25="")+(D7:D25=""),,
 IF((C7:C25>=E7)*(D7:D25>=5), "YES", "NO")))
```

[image: we]

---

### UPDATE 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUM(IF((C7:C25="")+(D7:D25=""),,
 IF((C7:C25>=E7)*(D7:D25>=5), 1, 0)))>0, "YES", "NO"))
```

Comment: I really appreciate your work on this so far--I've already learned a ton. This isn't quite where I want to get yet, and seems to be producing erroneous results. For those results, the only line to produce a YES should be Unit 2 ex 5 (C12 and D12) since C12 is above the reading goal and D12 is 5 or greater. Is there a way to examine all of that and produce a single YES or NO response in F7? These results would all be one student's responses, so we don't need a Y/N on each line--just an evaluation saying they had surpassed their goal or not. Thans again for your help so far.

Comment: hard to tell what exactly are you after. from your latest message I could think of several solutions (each with different result/outcome). as of now. formula checks for each value in column C if is higher than the goal and same time D column higher or equal to 5 - thats why each row is evaluated with yes or no

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear--this form tracks one student's timed reading scores. They work toward improving their speed by 20%. Each time they complete a timed reading and record their scores, I want the sheet to check if the new speed AND comprehension score are above the two minimums. Checking and providing a result for every row is a solution, but as it currently stands, it's giving incorrect results. All of the results here should be NO because the reading speeds do not reach the speed goal of 218, and the last one does not meet the comprehension minimum.